# Route Hashed in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-7

I want to hasher my urls in laravel, how do i do that?
I want the ids to be invisible and replace with random expressions

exemple: http//:laravel/update/id = http//:laravel/update/hvcd5213fc51dsssd£€#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding => Customizing The Resolution Logic, you can customize your route logic.

However you have passed hash value you have to call hash method(here it is md5) while retrieving information from database.

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return App\Models\User::where(DB::raw(md5('name')), $value)->firstOrFail();
    });
```

If you do not want to declare route like these, alternatively you can override resolveRouteBinding method as per the laravel docs.

Note: Here md5 is mysql hash function, if you are not retrieving from database you can hash your value in code and compare it with URL value itself.