# Laravel - Encoding does not work in getRouteKey - (Hashids\Hashids)

Tags: laravel, routes, obfuscation, hashids

I am trying to get my incrementing IDs hashed in my URLs. I cant seem get the encoding right, i followed both [this](https://sampo.co.uk/blog/masking-ids-in-urls-using-hash-ids-in-laravel) and [this](https://jenssegers.com/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5) tutorial, which didn't help. I tried the code i have in `getRouteKey()` in a controller, and it seems to be doing the job and hashing the ID as intended.

Anybody see what I am doing wrong?

```
public function getRouteKey()
{
    $key = $this->getKey();
    $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids('MySecretSalt', 5);
    return $hashids->encode($key);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Then I use binding/decoding as below;

```
    Route::model('property', Property::class);
    Route::bind('property', function ($value, $route) {
        $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids('MySecretSalt', 5);
        return $hashids->decode(intval($value))[0];
    });
```

My route is;

```
Route::get(
    '/{property}/vvv/',
    'PropertyController@property_dashboard'
)->name('property.dashboard');
```

Comment: Does it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175478/route-hashed-in-laravel-7/64175647#64175647

Comment: you are not turning the hashid back into a regular id, decoding it, anywhere

Comment: @lagbox I figured i would finish hashing logic first before i set up decoding, i added above, which doesn't work.  ```return $hashids->decode(intval($value))[0]``` this returns ```Undefined offset: 0
```, you think decoding is the problem for encoding?

Comment: what problem with encoding ... your own words say it is hashing it in the controller correctly ... so what is the actual issue of your question here?

Comment: @lagbox as i said, it only works in a controller (as below), not when I put in getRouteKey() function.  ```$key = $property->getKey();
    $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids('MySecretSalt', 5);
    return $hashids->encode($key);```

Comment: so what is happening when you are calling `$existingModel->getRouteKey()`?

Comment: it's giving me the id of the existing model.

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/mtvs/eloquent-hashids it does all this work for you on the fly

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Ok, just tried it. Hashing of id works, now when I do ``` $existingModel->getRouteKey() ``` i get the hashed id. But it still wont show up in my routes. All of my routes are still with the regular id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using a javascript front end and not blades so you don't have access to the Laravel route function.  If thats true and you are using something like Ziggy to create your routes, you can always just pass the hashid into ziggy's route method.  You can create a hashid attribute in your models to return to the front end then.